# How to make two different folder get resources from one folder?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a dynamic about page
[image]

```
<section class="page">

<header style="background-image: url('uploads/<?php echo $page[header_picture]; ?>'); background-position: center;"></header>

<div class="container">

    <?php echo $page['body_formatted']; ?>

</div>
```

and the Admin page

[image]

They both have same the same src

```
uploads/1473747556216.jpg
```

but my admin page are in a Admin folder.

How to make two different folder get resources from one folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each file would need to either provide an absolute or relative path to the source file.

If your directory structure is:

```
root
    about.php
    admin
        admin.php
    uploads
        1473747556216.jpg
```

Then **relative paths** would be:

```
"uploads/1473747556216.jpg" // from about.php
"../uploads/1473747556216.jpg" // from admin.php
```

Then **absolute paths** would be:

```
"http://whatever.com/uploads/1473747556216.jpg" // for either file
```

Then **relative from root** (if supported in your environment):

```
"/uploads/1473747556216.jpg" // from either file
```